# get image width & height

Tags: jquery

I am building website,i want to get image size i.e.width or height using jquery.
here is my code,

```
var photograf=('url(upload/'+ nm +'.jpg)');
var imgwidth=photograf.width();
var imgheight=photograf.height();
```

but it's not working.i know it's wrong but i have do above thing.
please help me other or correct way.
thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You're initializing `photograf` as a string, which has no `width()` or `height()` functions. Nowhere are you actually attempting to load an image, with jQuery or otherwise. In fact, there is no jQuery anywhere in your code.

You could either add the image to the page, and then find the resulting element's width/height, or create a new `Image` object:

```
photograf = new Image();
photograf.src = 'upload/' + nm + '.jpg');
var width = photograf.width;
var height = photograf.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you tagged with jquery, this is the jquery way to do what meagar has written:

```
var photograf = $("<img src='upload'"+nm+".jpg />");
var imgWidth = photograf.width;
var imgHeight = photograf.height;
```

Comment: sorry,but it returns width & height 0.  Thank you.