# how do I get the width inside the <img> tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following img tag:

```
   <img id="product-image" src="http://cf.test.com/images/store_logos/thumbnail/43f1ee4d5fe422e9440ab4afe065bbff899b24b0.jpg" width="228" height="304" style="opacity: 1;">
```

Trying to extract out the 304 height value:

```
$('#product-image').height();
```

However it always gives me the actual size of the image.
Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773322/get-image-width-height please check this this will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Width :"+$('#product-image').width());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$('#product-image').attr("height");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#product-image').prop("height");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the height after the image rendered:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#product-image').load(function() {
        alert($(this).height());
        alert($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using JQuery before 1.6 means

```
$('#product-image').attr("height")
```

other wise

```
$('#product-image').prop("height")
```

Will give you answer

Answer (score -3):

put the image in the div and take the size of div